# Run a application under current logged in user without passing credentials

Tags: c#, .net, process, windows-10, redmon

I am using redmon to redirect print job to my application.exe which is built in c#, its working fine with single user (on computer) but when i have another user on computer and i use it, redmon (which always run on system context) run's my application.exe in system context so i see my exe in taskbar but it don't show any UI where was on single user machine it runs my application under user-context so i am able to see my application open.

This whole problem of redmon is with windows 10 multiple user only

Now my plan is that i create an adapter in between in which i will create a exe which will be run by redmon in system context and then that exe run my application.exe in current loggedin user-context and i see UI of my application and interact with it.

I googled for it and every solution is using username and password and in my case i don't know who all would be using it and i won't be asking username/pass from users so i just want to run my exe using c# under current logged in user-context without passing username/pass.

please help me with that.

I have tried this code as well but its not running exe though it is returning True https://chasewright.com/2015/12/26/session0bypass/

NOTE: I am working on Active Directory environment.

Comment: Are you working with active directory for authentication or are all users local?

Comment: I am working on active directory environement, thanks for good comment

Comment: So "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name" does return different result when the exe gets ran by redmon instead of the user directly?

Comment: When i see in taskbar i can see that its running under System not like under current user like its working on my development machine where i have single user

Comment: When i create a new process with it it also get created/run with System (not current user)so i don't see its UI

Comment: Please provide some code how you recieve the data from redmon in your application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196358/discussion-between-dr-rajesh-rolen-and-colosso).